# Why my text is not responsive?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, font-size, responsive-slides

I use [responsiveslides](http://responsiveslides.com/) library to have responsive scrolling image.
So, I wish to utilise the same library to also obtain responsive scrolling text and I wrote this JS code to calculate font height, but it doesn't works:

```
function responsiveText()
{
    $('#footer').css('font-size', $('#footer').css('height'));
}
```

You can see my failed result in action [here](http://w3bcreation.it/rpi/stations/testNews)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things you may want to think about:

1) Your code that's setting the font-size will only be called once

2) You're setting the font-size for the hole container, why not just do it in css?

```
<style>
.rslides li {
    font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
```

3) But you want it to be responsive, right? Then, you'll have to take the number of characters and width of the container into account, multiply that with something, set that value to the font-size of the text-element, and do this for every text-element you have. Or not exactly, take a look at this code instead:

So something like this:

```
 function responsiveText() {

    var ratio = 1/2; // character width/height
    var padding = 10;
    var width = $("#newsSlider").outerWidth()-padding*2;
    var height = $("#footer").outerHeight()-padding*2;

    $("#newsSlider").children().each(function () {
        var li = $(this); // one text element/list item
        var len = li.text().length; // number of characters
        var fw = width/len; // maximal character width = width/number of characters
        var fh = height; // maximal character height

        // We want fw/fh be so close to ratio as possible by changeing nr of lines
        var nrofl = 1;
        for (; nrofl<5; nrofl++) {
            var nnrofl = nrofl+1;
            var newRatio = (width/(len/nnrofl)) / (height/nnrofl);
            if (Math.abs(newRatio-ratio)<Math.abs(fw/fh-ratio)) {
                nrofl = nnrofl;
                fw = (width/(len/nrofl));
                fh = (height/nrofl);
            } else break;
        }

        // One thing's missing if you want a perfect result:
        // Go through the text and insert new lines to make sure
        // there will be nrofl lines. Not going to do it here though.

        // Fontsize is min of fw/ratio and fh
        var fs = Math.min(fw/ratio, fh);

        // For testing only
        //console.log(Math.round(fs), ratio, Math.round(fw), fh, width, height, nrofl, len);

        // Do not forget to round it up to integer value
        li.css('font-size', Math.round(fs)+'px');
    });

}

$(function() {

    // image slideshow
    $("#imageSlider").responsiveSlides({
        timeout: 20*1000,
    });

    // news slideshow
    $("#newsSlider").responsiveSlides({
        timeout: 5*1000,
    });


    // resposive news 
    $(window).resize(function(){
        responsiveText();   
    });
    responsiveText();

});
```

Try to replace your old code with this one. (Edit) Now it should work pretty well! Tested it for a while, try resizing your browser! Only thing left (not critical though) is to make sure there'll be the right amount of lines. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Leonard,
I tried to apply your solution but as you can see in the updated page the result is almost the same.
Some news are cut and are not readable

Comment: Hi, 
I removed "padding" from footer div and now all news are readable.
So, I realized that some short news has little font dimension. Why?

Comment: Yeah, as I said, the values (50, 20 and 30) was just examples. Right now, the width/len usually results in a value less than 20, thus getting the font-size 30. However, shorter texts will get a greater value, and if it's greater then 20 but less than 30 it will result in a smaller font-size. So yeah, my example values wasn't that perfect..

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to round the size, css wants only integers for px values: Math.round(fs)+'px'

Comment: Also, if we want several lines, we have to take the height into account too... and it seems like I wrote to fast, the fontsize is, as you said, the height and not the width of the characters, and in the font you used, it does also seems like the width is half the height..

Comment: Hi,
wainting your answer I had to apply a sirty solution for my client.
So, I am interested to better know how to apply your idea to my problem.

Comment: In the example site you gave me, http://w3bcreation.it/rpi/stations/testNews, in /rpi/js/call_responsiveSlides.js, replace the whole file content with the code above. Also, at the "One thing's missing.." comment, do something like txt = li.text();arr = txt.split(" "); idx = Math.round(arr.length/nrofl);newtxt="";for (i = 0; i<nrofl-1; i++) { newtxt += (new array of arr items idx*i to idx*(i+1)).join(" ")+"<br/>";}li.html(newtxt); to fix the line issue..